# Strange behaviour when creating/deleting subdomains

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting, subdomain, cache

This can be a DNS cache issue from my local machine, but I am not sure. This is what happens. I have a domain that does not use wildcard subdomains, so they have to be created.

Without creating the domain, and I point my browser to test.domain.com, I get a page server not found. Now when I create the subdomain, I keep getting the same problem.

Now when I first create the domain, without ever visiting the page, I get the normal page, but now when I delete the subdomain, it never goes away.

Can this be a DNS cache issue, I am working on a shared environment, maybe the router has a cache but I doubt that. Can this have something to do with my setup.

I have tried to use the [Google DNS hosting](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/), but this gives me the same results.

I have also tried some tools that clear my local DNS cache, they were some add-ons for FireFox.

Anyone have any ideas what can be the problem. Are there any tests I can do to see if there is some kind of cache between me and the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long did you wait before making the DNS change and testing it? Most DNS entries are cached for a minimum of 30 minutes (did you see a Time to Live, or TTL setting when creating your subdomain? Thats the number of seconds that the record will be cached for).

This is the **minimum** time you'll have to wait before the correct record will show up (it's meant to be the *maximum* time, but isn't for the following reasons). Badly behaved DNS servers (of which there are a lot) will totally ignore your advertised TTL and cache it for as long as they like.

A fairly good way of knowing if the change has taken place is to use your favourite `nslookup` tool. When you're in `nslookup`, query:

```
test.example.com nsX.dnsserver.com
```

(replace `test.example.com` with your real domain, and `nsX.dnsserver.com` with the address of a nameserver your domain uses).

Note that that method is not always 100% accurate, as some DNS providers will respond to ANY domain request, but if you visit the address you just get a parking page.

Comment: +1 Ah I see, I did not wait, I thought the subdomain would be available instantly after I restarted httpd.

Comment: The following questions might help you understand DNS propogation: http://serverfault.com/questions/82251/why-is-it-called-dns-propagation and http://serverfault.com/questions/9360/previewing-site-during-dns-propagation and http://serverfault.com/questions/125371/how-long-does-it-take-for-an-a-record-to-propagate